# Deploy static website on port 5000 with docker and nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

I try to deploy a simple static `index.html` and `style.css` website with docker.

```
server {

    #root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name data-mastery.com; # managed by Certbot

     location /blog {
       proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
     }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/data-mastery.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/data-mastery.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = data-mastery.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name data-mastery.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

This is my simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I started the container with the following command:

```
sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 blog
```

I am not sure that this line means when I run `docker ps`:

```
80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp
```

Is everything correct here or not?

How can I make it running on port 5000?

Thank you!

Comment: You copied the html over but not the nginx config or the letsencrypt files

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**
Your use case is addressed in [nginx docker image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx), so I'll paraphrase it.

```
$ docker run --name my-blog -v /path/to/your/static/content/:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx
```

Alternatively, a simple Dockerfile can be used to generate a new image that includes the necessary content (which is a much cleaner solution than the bind mount above):

```
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Place this file in the same directory as your directory of content , run `docker build -t my-blog .`, then start your container:

```
$ docker run --name my-blog -d my-blog
```

Exposing external port

```
$ docker run --name some-nginx -d -p 8080:80 some-content-nginx
```

Then you can hit http://localhost:8080 or http://host-ip:8080 in your browser.

**Initial answer:**
You should try something like:

```
sudo docker run -p 80:5000 blog
```

docker will proxy connection to localhost:5000 to your_container:80

on your_container:80 nginx is listening and will proxy to your_container:500 where your blog is answering

I hope that helps

Comment: unfortunately it does not work :-(. No errors, just nothing happens

Comment: @DataMastery is the nginx conf file your own? because your usecase is descibe in nginx docker image documentation, and it should be fairly simple:https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx Look at "Hosting some simple static content" and "Exposing external port"

Comment: I decided to not use docker for this kind of usecase. Too much overhead. I use a simple alias solution, no reverse proxying and so on :-)